# What does WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 }) mean in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, insert

I inserted a document into a mongoDB collection, and received the message `WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })`

```
db.myColl1.insert({title: 'MongoDB Overview', description: 'MongoDB is no sql database',by: 'tutorials point',url: 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com',tags: ['mongodb', 'database', 'NoSQL'],likes: 100})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

What does `WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })` mean?

Answer (score 3):

> > What does WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 }) mean?

Whenever you write to the database, you'll get a WriteResult object that tells us if the operation was successful or not.

In your case, nInserted stands for the number of documents inserted.

Answer (score 2):

That is the expected behaivior of MongoDB. Try using find or findOne to see the inserted object in the collection.

```
db.myColl1.find({title: 'MongoDB Overview'});
```

or

```
db.myColl1.findOne({title: 'MongoDB Overview'});
```

Usually findOne returns an object with a better format than find, but you can use pretty in the end of a find operation to get a better format.

```
db.myColl1.find().pretty()
```

Answer (score 1):

This means it's inserted. Try to execute this:

```
    db.myColl1.find()
```

and you see it's there.

Answer (score 1):

Commands that write to the database, (save, insert, update, remove, etcetera) 
return a writeResult object, so that the application may know if the 
document(s) were written correctly, and may perform different logic 
based on the results.